# Will SSH use a host configuration when we connect via the IP directly or via a different DNS entry?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, dns, openssh

Say you have a host configuration as following:

```
Host work-server-1
  Hostname a.b.c.d
  ConnectTimeout 5
```

I have two questions:

1. Will SSH apply the `ConnectTimeout 5` configuration setting when you log into the server via `ssh pritzl@a.b.c.d` instead of `pritzel@work-server-1`?
2. As a related question, assume that there is a DNS entry `secret-server.work.com` which resolves to `a.b.c.d`. Will now `ConnectTimeout 5` be used when you login with `ssh pritzl@secret-server.work.com`? Note that `secret-server.work.com` is not mentioned in the configuration above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will SSH apply the `ConnectTimeout 5` configuration setting when you log into the server via `ssh pritzl@a.b.c.d` instead of `pritzel@work-server-1`?

No.

Only the `Host` directive is considered when deciding what directives are applied. It's as simple as that.

Quoting [man page for `ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config):

> The configuration files contain sections separated by `Host` specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification. **The matched host name is usually the one given on the command line** (see the `CanonicalizeHostname` option for exceptions).

Comment: I appreciate your sense for details Martin.